# Put event handler on a HTML button without overriding its default functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to modify a contact form so that the submit button is disabled for five seconds after being clicked, to prevent accidental repeat submissions.

The problem is that disabling the button (by setting its 'disabled' attribute) prevents it from actually submitting. Setting any kind of even handler on them seems to override the default action, even though I'm not using .preventDefault();.

Is there a way I can bind a click event handler to a button that will operate in addition to its pre-existing functionality?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 jQuery(function() {
    jQuery(":submit").on('click', function(e) {
        jQuery(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });
 });
```

Comment: have you tried to wrap the "disabling" function in a `setTimeout`?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue at all? Post the code you have.

Comment: On the other hand, if the form is submitted, why do you expect the submit button to be disabled when you reload the page ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried wrapping it in a setTimeout. That results the natural functionality working, but the disabling function not! @adeneo I updated the original post with the code I'm using.

Comment: Again, when you submit a form the page reloads, and all javascript is lost ?

Comment: @adeneo But that isn't a problem. I'm not trying to prevent people from ever submitting another form, I'm just trying to prevent multiple identical forms being sent in by people who doubleclick, or impatiently click over and over because it's going slow, etc.

Comment: And that's not an issue, you can disable the button on submit, but once the page has reloaded, the button isn't disabled any more, and disabling the button after it's clicked does in no way prevent the form from submitting -> http://jsfiddle.net/5n2Jm/

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/souviiik/4AsHc/

HTML

```
<form action="#" id="myForm">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btnSubmit">
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
var st;

$("#myForm").on("submit", function () {
    if ($(".btnSubmit").hasClass("btnDisabled")) {
        return false;
    } else {
        alert("clicked!");
        $(".btnSubmit").addClass("btnDisabled");
        st = setInterval(enableBtn, 5000);
    }
});

function enableBtn() {
    $(".btnSubmit").removeClass("btnDisabled");
    clearInterval(st);
}
```

CSS

```
.btnSubmit {
    background: #d33;
    color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #d33;
}
.btnDisabled {
    background: #fefefe;
    color: #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use submit button only once you can use jquery .one() function